# How can I pass PayPal IPN callback throw idevaffiliate to a framework?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

We are started to use [iDevAffiliate](http://www.idevdirect.com/idevaffiliate.php).

Based on [following instructions](http://www.idevlibrary.com/docs/Paypal_Button_Creation.pdf),
we made a PayPal's Buy Now button which has `notify_url` attribute pointed to our iDevAffiliate server (`/paypal_ipn_buynow.php`).

What I don't understand is, how now PayPal can notify our server about a purchase, if all requests are going to iDevAffiliate server?

How can I pass a request to our server, without hacking the code of iDevAffiliate?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to your server first and then redirect to the affiliate url from your server. If that is not possible maybe your affiliate provides some king of API that you can use to check the status

Cheers

Comment: It would't work because iDevAffiliate validates `$_POST` that is comes from PayPal.

Comment: Then you need to either consume from an iDevAffiliate API or a PayPal one

Comment: I didn't find any API from iDevAffiliate. Most of documentation is really basic, explains how to copy files via ftp. PayPal's API is limited with `notify_url` callback.

Comment: Not trying to be the devils advocate here, but if the solution you're trying doesn't fit your needs you should move to something else. Have you tried talking to iDevAffiliate customer support, in my experience theres very little things that haven't been tried before, I'm sure they had this issue before.

Comment: I've asked them already, waiting for reply. Unfortunately we have to use them, there are no alternatives for our business. I'll bring an answer here if any.

Comment: you could try one last resource. Redirect the PayPal request to your server and then using curl forward the exact same request to iDev. I sounds a bit dodgy but if nothing else works...

Comment: Claudio Pinto & Mr.M you a right, you can validate PayPal incoming just by `$_POST` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/. I'll try to forward a request to iDevAffiliate.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

PayPal sends IPN request to the website you specified in the `notify_url` filed. Here you want to specify name of the script on your domain which will listen IPN requests comming from PayPal. For example: http://yourwebsite.com/listen_ipn.php where `listen_ipn.php` is your PHP script.

Please note that if you are using framework, then you can implement your IPN listener in controller's action. Then your URL might be like this: http://yourdomain.com/controllerID/actionID

To implement IPN listener use the following library https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN. This library is really useful and easy to use.

Here is example code:

```
<?php

include('ipnlistener.php');

$listener = new IpnListener();
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

try {
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // fatal error trying to process IPN.
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {
    // IPN response was "VERIFIED"
} else {
    // IPN response was "INVALID"
}

?>
```

When you receive and parse IPN request, you would maybe like to update some data in your database,for example to allow your user to access to some data beacuse user paid.

When you do that, you have to notify iDevAffiliate that payment occured. You have all data from PayPal in your PHP `$_POST` array. So in order to notify iDevAffiliate, just make POST request containing all data that PayPal sent you (again, you can retrieve this data from your `$_POST` array) to iDevAffiliate listener from your website .

For sending POST requests, you can use cURL libraray. Here is example:

```
$url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE**: PayPal may send you **several IPN requests for the same transaction**, so make sure you have some flag column in your DB which tells you that IPN is already processed.

When you send data to iDevAffiliate, then circle is closed.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on official documentation, they require to send all IPN requests directly to iDevAffiliate. http://www.idevlibrary.com/docs/Paypal_Button_Creation.pdf Originally we had our own IPN listener of course.

Comment: And, I think, iDevAffiliate validates `$_POST` that comes from PayPal. Otherwise you could create fake requests and create commission from those fake visits.